# NRPE CentOS 7 Could not open config directory

Tags: centos, nagios

I just installed NRPE on CentOS 7 via Chef. This is the same recipe that I use for all of my CentOS 6 servers - and works there. NRPE starts up but errors out here:

```
Jun 13 15:12:21 myserver nrpe[3667]: Could not open config directory '/etc/nagios/nrpe.d' for reading.
Jun 13 15:12:21 myserver nrpe[3667]: Continuing with errors...
```

All of the server configs are under /etc/nagios/nrpe.d. Here's my cfg:

```
pid_file=/var/run/nrpe.pid
server_port=5666
nrpe_user=nagios
nrpe_group=nagios
dont_blame_nrpe=0
debug=0
command_timeout=60
allowed_hosts=127.0.0.1,192.168.1.14
include_dir=/etc/nagios/nrpe.d
```

Here are the permissions on /etc/nagios/nrpe.d:

```
# ls -atlr /etc/nagios/
-rwxrwxrwx.  1 nagios nagios  248 Jun 13 14:45 nrpe.cfg
drwxrwxrwx.  2 nagios nagios   89 Jun 13 14:51 nrpe.d
```

**How can I get NRPE to read the configs in the config directory?**

Comment: I ended up using the default CentOS 7 settings  - /etc/nrpe.d. Now my commands are being recognized. I'm 90% positive it's an Selinux policy issue but I don't have time to dig thru their code and figure out how to loosen this up.

Comment: I ran across the same thing using the [nrpe chef cookbook](https://github.com/sous-chefs/nrpe). The problem was the `/etc/nagios` is set as `/etc/nagios(/.*)?    system_u:object_r:nagios_etc_t:s0` and the cookbook uses `include_dir = "#{node['nrpe']['conf_dir']}/nrpe.d"`. The rpm creates `/etc/nrpe.d` which just inherits `system_u:object_r:etc_t:s0` from `/etc`. It seems that the nrpe agent can't read either `nrpe_etc_t` or `nagios_etc_t` directories but it can read from `etc_t`.

Answer (score 3):

I have come across the same issue. Please find the below steps for resolution.

1. Check the permissions of `/etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg` file and then SELinux status using `sestatus` command or `getenforce` command. If it shows "Disabled" then no issues. If it shows "Permissive" then no issues, but if it shows "Enforcing" then do the following steps.
2. If you need SELinux to be in enforcing mode, then check the SELinux policy file context using the following command,

   ```
   # pwd
   /etc/nagios
   # ls -Z
   -rw-r--r--. root root system_u:object_r:nrpe_etc_t:s0  nrpe.cfg
   ```
3. If the file context is different then change it to **nrpe_etc_t** using the following command.

   ```
   # semanage fcontext -a -t nrpe_etc_t "/etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg"
   # restorecon -R -v /etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg
   ```

I have tested the same in CentOS 7.

Answer (score 1):

Turn on debug in nrpe.cfg and restart the service, if you see the error message like "nrpe can not read configure dir /etc/nagios/nrpe.d".  That means the selinux caused the problem.

You may check and turn off selinux(if no security convern).

## getenforce

Enforcing

## setenforce 0

## getenforce

Permissive

Then restart nrpe with "service nrpe restart".
Now it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you look at the permissions and ownership on the /etc/nagios directory as well.

You could also su to the nagios user and start moving(cd) up the directory tree to identify where the permissions break down.

Comment: Good advice. No luck, though. You might want to try commenting on a post before answering. Some people might downvote this and I'd hate for you to lose your karma :)

Comment: I wish I could.  It won't let me add a comment to the main question until I have 50 reputation points.   I appreciate the advice, though!  I've received such a benefit from StackExchange et al, that I wanted to try to contribute something back.